# How to bind to a dictionary entry with key ending in '{'?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to bind to a value in a dictionary property of an object. The dictionary key of this value is a string ending in '{'. How do I express this in XAML?

I presumably need to escape this character somehow.

Example XAML that doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribs[test{]}" />
```

Here `Attribs` is a property on the datacontext object of type `IDictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XAML works, by avoiding using a binding expression and instead using a Binding element:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text><Binding Path="Attribs[test{]"/></TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have tested the following XAML fragment, and it seems to work fine:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribs[test\{]}"/>
```

The \ escape character is explained in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that too - more concise than my solution.